# Data Binding plugin uses old version of Support library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-databinding

I am getting this error after updating Support libraries to 27.0.2.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (21.0.3) and runtime (27.0.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

I have data binding enabled in my project.

```
dataBinding.enabled = true
```

When I run

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath
```

This is what I get:

```
+--- com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3 -> 26.0.2
|    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.0-dev -> 3.0.1
+--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.1
+--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1
|    +--- com.android.databinding:library:1.3 -> 1.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.0-dev -> 3.0.1
+--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1
|    \--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-analyzer:1.5.1
|         +--- com.squareup.haha:haha:2.0.3
|         \--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-watcher:1.5.1
+--- project :general
|    +--- com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.1
|    \--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1
|    \--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.8.1
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:gifdecoder:4.2.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:disklrucache:4.2.0
|    \--- com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.2.0
\--- com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.2
```

This clearly shows that Android data binding library is using support v4 with version 21.0.3, which is causing conflicts.

Can anyone help?

Comment: this issue is not caused by data binding because its not using any dependency. just do it Build -> Clean Project or Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: @HemantParmar : No, It is not working

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568032/android-data-binding-dependency-conflict-with-the-support-library/41579908#41579908

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 3.x or Android Studio 2.x? I think we updated data binding to use the newer dependencies for AS 3.0

Comment: @GeorgeMount: Simply put, [that has not happened](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64909326).

Comment: Ah, must be 3.1. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I find the solution by myself:
Add below in your app module (not in library or any other module):

```
android {
...
    configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLib}"
            resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLib}"
            resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:design:${supportLib}"
            resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLib}"
            resolutionStrategy.force "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:${lifecycleExtensions}"
        }
}
```

It will force gradle to use updated dependencies and solve the conflict errors.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `dependencies` closure:

```
  implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2"
```

This will cause Gradle to upgrade the `support-v4` dependency to match the rest of your Support Library artifacts.